# Splitting a string error: SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

Tags: python, database, web

I'm pulling address from my site because I didn't make a backup in xml format. I got it working, except now I want to divide the city and the country by the comma.

Here is what I have so far

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python2.7

    from requests import get
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

    f = open('scraped.csv', 'wb')
    f.write('"Name","URL","Address Line 1","new_line1","new_line2","Phone"\n')

    rej = open('rejected.csv', 'wb')
    rej.write('"ID"\n')

    for i in xrange(1, 7397 + 1):
        try:
            url = "http://map.crossfit.com/affinfo.php?a={}&t=0".format(i)
            text = get(url).text
            splitted = [foo.replace('\n', ' ') for foo in text.split('<br />')]
            soup = Soup(splitted[0])
            _, addr1, new_line1 = line1.split(',')[0], new_line2 = line1.split(',')[1] + ', ' +         line2, phone = [foo.replace('"', '""') for foo in splitted]
            name = soup.text
            url = soup.b.a['href']
            line = '"' + '","'.join((name, url, addr1, addr2, phone)) + '"'
            print line
            f.write((line + '\n').encode('utf8'))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
        except:
            print 'Rejected: {}'.format(i)
            rej.write('{}\n'.format(i))

    f.close()
    rej.close()
```

The error I get is:

```
      File "/Users/Spencer/Downloads/xmlmaker.py", line 18
        _, addr1, new_line1 = line1.split(',')[0], new_line2 = line1.split(',')[1] + ', ' + line2,         phone = [foo.replace('"', '""') for foo in splitted]
    SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

Any ideas? I was looking and saw maybe some mispelling, but I just don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put those statements on separate lines:

```
_, addr1, new_line1 = line1.split(',')[0]
new_line2 = line1.split(',')[1] + ', ' + line2
phone = [foo.replace('"', '""') for foo in splitted]
```

Use `;` to separate statements on a single line not `,`. But it is less readable so it's better to put them on separate lines :

```
>>> x = 1; y = 2
>>> x,y
(1, 2)
```

From [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements):

> Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are
>   generally discouraged.

Comment: Grasping at straws here, but maybe they thought your answer should state even more strongly that semicolons are usually a bad idea? (If so, I disagree completely… but at least that would be a somewhat rational explanations; I can't think of any other reason someone would downvote other than "I don't like the name Ashwini" or "How do I work this trackpad?")

Comment: Thanks! but I now everything gets rejected. Any ideas? I'm new to python.

Comment: @Zargle what value are you trying to assign to `_`?

Comment: @Zargle: What do you mean "everything gets rejected"? If you have a new problem, please create a new question that describes your specific problem, instead of trying to tack it onto this one. (Also, if either answer solved the initial problem for you, accept it.)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot treat assignments as values, i.e. there can not be an expression to the left of `=` (and only one `=` per line except for chained assignments like `a = b = c = 0`). Replace the monster line

```
_, addr1, new_line1 = line1.split(',')[0], new_line2 = line1.split(',')[1] + ', ' +         line2, phone = [foo.replace('"', '""') for foo in splitted]
```

with something like

```
phone = [foo.replace('"', '""') for foo in splitted]
new_line2 = line1.split(',')[1] + ', ' +  line2
_, addr1, new_line1 = line1.split(',')[0]
```

Comment: This is mildly misleading—there _can_ be more than one `=` per line in the case of chained additions, like `a = b = c = 2`. But I don't think it's a serious problem with the answer.

Comment: @abarnert True, fixed in the answer. You can also concatenate multiple statements with `;` in a single line, left that out for simplicity.

Comment: Agreed, you don't need to explain semicolons to people unless they're really relevant (which they rarely are)…